# Slow SQL query with SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, performance

I have two SQL queries to count co-occurrences between id2 values among different id1 values. The sample table looks like

```
id1 | id2
101 | 1
101 | 2
101 | 3
102 | 2
102 | 3
102 | 4
103 | 15
103 | 3
103 | 4
```

and the desired output is:

```
A  B Count
1  2 1
1  3 2
2  3 4
1  4 2
2  4 3
3  4 4
1 15 1
2 15 2
3 15 2
4 15 1
```

Both solutions are pasted below.

```
-- Solution 1
SELECT bar.id2 AS A, foo.id2 AS B, COUNT(*) AS Count
FROM
  (SELECT * FROM TestTab) AS bar,
  (SELECT * FROM TestTab) AS foo
WHERE bar.id1 <> foo.id1
  AND bar.id2 < foo.id2
GROUP BY bar.id2, foo.id2

-- Solution 2
SELECT bar.id2 AS A, foo.id2 AS B, COUNT(*) AS Count
FROM TestTab AS bar
JOIN TestTab AS foo
  ON bar.id1 <> foo.id1
WHERE bar.id2 < foo.id2
GROUP BY bar.id2, foo.id2
```

Both queries work fine on small tables (i.e., 100 - 1000 rows), but I need to query much larger table (e.g., 100.000 rows). I wonder how to speed up the queries and improve performance. Thanks in advance for any pointers.

```
- Create table TestTab and insert dummy data
CREATE TABLE TestTab
INSERT INTO TestTab VALUES
  (101,1),
  (101,2),
  (101,3),
  (102,2),
  (102,3),
  (102,4),
  (103,15),
  (103,3),
  (103,4)
```

Comment: General rule: any field used in a where/join/group clause should have an index on it.

Comment: as a minor aside, I'd suggest using "INNER JOIN" where you want to exclude NULLs - this will also enforce use of the ON clause.

Comment: Do you have another table with distinct-only values of id2, and if so what is it called?

Comment: Solution 1 is a non-ANSI syntax query.  It should be thrown into the nearest volcano asap.

Comment: Should the id1 criterion be `bar.id1 = foo.id1`, instead of `bar.id1 <> foo.id1`?

Comment: Create a composite index on `(id1, id2)` on the testTab table.. it will optimize the query..

Comment: @Meherzad: In that order it probably won't (unless I was correct in thinking that the join criterion should be `bar.id1 = foo.id1`), but it *might* improve matters if the index is in the order `(id2, id1)`.

Comment: @Mark Bannister No, I haven't. But it's not problem to create it.

Comment: @Mark Bannister: the criterion `bar.id1 <> foo.id1` is right, while we would like to count co-occurrences between different `id1`s.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest adding an index on `id2` to TestTab (if one doesn't already exist) and then try running the following:

```
select distinct id2 into #id2 from TestTab;

SELECT bar.id2 AS A, foo.id2 AS B, COUNT(*) AS Count
FROM #id2 AS bar
JOIN #id2 AS foo ON bar.id2 < foo.id2
JOIN TestTab AS buz ON bar.id2 = buz.id2
JOIN TestTab AS fuz ON foo.id2 = fuz.id2
WHERE buz.id1 <> fuz.id1
GROUP BY bar.id2, foo.id2;
```

(If you already have a table with the distinct values of id2 on it, skip creating the temporary table and use that instead.)

Comment: [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/59b19/5/2) to see the identical result sets. I added an order by for easier comparison. Why do suggest the temporary table and these additional joins?

Comment: @OlafDietsche: Yes, the result sets should match - it's the performance for a large TestTab that should differ. I would expect the performance of the original query to be proportional to n*n (where n is the total number of rows in TestTab), while the performance of the proposed query should be proportional to d*d*2*n (where d is the number of distinct values) - I think.

Comment: So the performance is better, if there are a lot of duplicate values in the `id2` column. Thank you for the quick reply.

Comment: @Mark Bannister: Query took about 15 minutes to count 5.013.314 pairs. Is this expected (time)? Before I created 2 indices: `CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX Idx1 ON TestTab (id1, id2)` and `CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX Idx2 ON #id2 (id2)`

Comment: @Andrej: How does this compare with your original queries and/or the other approaches? I had no specific expectations about the performance of this approach, other than that it *ought* to be significantly faster than the existing queries - and I wasn't entirely certain about that, which is why I suggested *trying* it.

Answer (score 1):

Both queries are joins and equivalent.

The first one is an implicit join with additional subselects. It might be slower, if SQL Server doesn't optimize the subselects away.

As others already observed, add indexes to the join condition column `id1` and the where clause column `id2`, if you haven't done so already.